# How is this type of video player called?

Tags: media-player, joomla-extensions

I want to make a joomla site that has this kind of video player.

https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/preview#close

I mean when you click on the video name, that opens video player. I tried to google for joomla extension that would enable it for me, but unsuccessfully because I don't know what for to search. Also if someone knows some good solution to this task that I could easily implement (I'm planning to make site with joomla) I would be grateful.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

After about 10 minutes looking through the source code i found something interest and it's what you want.

http://mediaelementjs.com/

I just saw that it's free but nothing about joomla. But i think it's easy to install as standalone extension ;)

Hope could helpya!
:)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but can you tell me where actually you found that this player can do what I want? I was looking through their site (mediaelementsjs.com) and have not found it in any demo or as option available. And also as I see there is joomla plugin available. :)  Once again thank you for help.

Comment: There is more and an updated joomla extension

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-players/video-players-a-gallery/14836

http://videojs.com/

I thought you just want a video player (which you found now). What left is that you have to integrate it into your joomla site and set up the link that it pop up on the same page.